# Infinite background while loop in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to write a QT program in Python and it is supposed to continuously look for updates. Just like

```
while(True):
   doSomething()
```

would do in a console based program.

Is there a specific slot which I can connect to for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QThread`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html) to create loop what your want. Your can find example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583418/implementing-qprogressbar-against-a-class/25584954#25584954), [here](http://orangepalantir.org/topicspace/index.php?idnum=33) and a lot of in google search result. `QThread` i subclass in `QObject` so your can connect just like `QWidget` old-style or new-style signal.

Answer (score 2):

It depends from what you want to achieve.

QThread is one solution.

You also can solve this by using a QTimer with a timeout of zero. Such a timer executes 
the connected slot whenever nothing other needs to be done by the event loop (like some background task).

Depending from what you do also a QTimer with a decent timeout can be the solution (like polling for an event).

As I said, it depends from what you want to do.