# To close a QtGui Window

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I am a beginner in python . Recently i got stuck in a problem . Problem is stated as follows : I needed a progressbar in my app . So i googled and found a similar code . With this code even if the progress is 100% main window is not closing (while the progress window closes).
Please help me in resolving this issue .

After searching i found the following code :

```
from threading import *
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
class QCustomThread (QtCore.QThread):
    startLoad    = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    progressLoad = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    statusLoad   = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomThread, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.wasCanceled = False
    def run (self):
        # Simulate data load estimation
        numberOfprogress = 100
        self.startLoad.emit(numberOfprogress)
        for progress in range(numberOfprogress + 1):
            # Delay
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if not self.wasCanceled:
                self.progressLoad.emit(progress)
            else:
                break
        self.statusLoad.emit(True if progress == numberOfprogress else False)
        self.exit(0)
    def cancel (self):
        self.wasCanceled = True
class QCustomMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(QCustomMainWindow, self).__init__()        
        self.loadingQProgressDialog = QtGui.QProgressDialog(self)
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setLabelText('Processing')
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setCancelButtonText('Cancel')
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        self.startWork()
    def startWork (self):
        myQCustomThread = QCustomThread(self)
        def startLoadCallBack (numberOfprogress):
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setMinimum(0)
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setMaximum(numberOfprogress)
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.show()
        def progressLoadCallBack (progress):
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setValue(progress)
        def statusLoadCallBack (flag):
            print 'SUCCESSFUL' if flag else 'FAILED'
        myQCustomThread.startLoad.connect(startLoadCallBack)
        myQCustomThread.progressLoad.connect(progressLoadCallBack)
        myQCustomThread.statusLoad.connect(statusLoadCallBack)
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.canceled.connect(myQCustomThread.cancel)
        myQCustomThread.start()
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.hide()
def app():
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomMainWindow = QCustomMainWindow()
    myQCustomMainWindow.show()
    print 'main complete'
##    myQCustomMainWindow.loadingQProgressDialog.hide()
    (myQApplication.exec_())
def deep():
    print 'hello'
    app()
    print 'hi'
if __name__=="__main__":
    deep()
    deep()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your found my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583418/implementing-qprogressbar-against-a-class/25584954#25584954) of progress bar ;). But my answer to show how to implement `QThread` open file, not close window until 100% progress. But simply to close is, when progress is successful, close it by use [`self.close()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#close) in `def statusLoadCallBack (flag)`;

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class QCustomThread (QtCore.QThread):
    startLoad    = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    progressLoad = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    statusLoad   = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomThread, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.wasCanceled = False

    def run (self):
        # Simulate data load estimation
        numberOfprogress = 100
        self.startLoad.emit(numberOfprogress)
        for progress in range(numberOfprogress + 1):
            # Delay
            time.sleep(0.001)
            if not self.wasCanceled:
                self.progressLoad.emit(progress)
            else:
                break
        self.statusLoad.emit(True if progress == numberOfprogress else False)
        self.exit(0)

    def cancel (self):
        self.wasCanceled = True

class QCustomMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(QCustomMainWindow, self).__init__()        
        self.loadingQProgressDialog = QtGui.QProgressDialog(self)
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setLabelText('Processing')
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setCancelButtonText('Cancel')
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        self.startWork()

    def startWork (self):
        myQCustomThread = QCustomThread(self)
        def startLoadCallBack (numberOfprogress):
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setMinimum(0)
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setMaximum(numberOfprogress)
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.show()
        def progressLoadCallBack (progress):
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setValue(progress)
        def statusLoadCallBack (flag):
            print 'SUCCESSFUL' if flag else 'FAILED'
            if flag:
                self.close()
        myQCustomThread.startLoad.connect(startLoadCallBack)
        myQCustomThread.progressLoad.connect(progressLoadCallBack)
        myQCustomThread.statusLoad.connect(statusLoadCallBack)
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.canceled.connect(myQCustomThread.cancel)
        myQCustomThread.start()

def app():
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomMainWindow = QCustomMainWindow()
    myQCustomMainWindow.show()
    print 'main complete'
    (myQApplication.exec_())

def deep():
    print 'hello'
    app()
    print 'hi'

if __name__=="__main__":
    deep()
    deep()
```

Comment: Please tell how to pass values(variables) to :class QCustomThread from function app.

Comment: Try read document at link https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html . It's same any language.